# Spacebars retrieving template from javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I've currently migrated my meteor to 0.8, but i'm having some headache migrating from handlebars to spacebars.

Currently in my javascript function, I retrieve a template and put it inside a leaflet popup.

```
var marker = new L.Marker(...)
.addTo(map).bindPopup(Template.PopupForm({
  data: data
}));
```

What is the equivalent for this in spacebars ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Template.name` no longer returns just HTML content, it returns a Template object that needs to be rendered and inserted via Meteor's methods. Since you need to pass a ready DOM element to Leaflet's method, you need to create an intermediate div. First you'll render your template to that div, then you can pass it to Leaflet's `bindPopup` method.

Code:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(Template.PopupForm, {
  data: data,
}), div);

L.Marker(...).addTo(map).bindPopup(div);
```

Comment: Thank you that was it! just for the future, there's a missing ) after  }. `UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(Template.PopupForm, {
  data: data,
}), div);`